# Excel SUMIF looking for letters in an order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this set of data

```
     A           B
1 A768BC10      2300
2 AB7697C787    2030
3 AC879B87      1760
4 AB56779       1490
```

Now I want to get the Sum of the values where A is before B and C is after B I was wondering if there is a way to do it I tried using RIGHT() but the LEN() I was using to get the strings length was giving problems so

```
=SUMIF(B1:B7,--(RIGHT(RIGHT(A1:A7,--LEN(A1:A7)-IFERROR(FIND("A",A1:A7),0)),LEN(RIGHT(A1:A7,LEN(A1:A7)-IFERROR(FIND("A",A1:A7),99)))-IFERROR(FIND("B",RIGHT(A1:A7,LEN(A1:A7)-IFERROR(FIND("A",A1:A7),99))),99))="*C"))
```

So I am wondering is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  wildcards:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"*A*B*C*")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Would i be also able to get an average for values with A*B*C?